# How do I access the additional columns in models that inherit from a parent-type when querying Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

In my project, I have a parent table `'Tasks'` with fields like `'owner_id'` and `'title'`. I also have two specific variations of Tasks called `'TaskFind'` and `'TaskFix'`. These both extend the `'Tasks'` table and offer additional columns.

I have no problem creating instance of the children models using Bookshelf's `forge`. But when I try and query for **all** Tasks, I don't have access to the fields in the extended models.

For example, pretend I have a database with one instance of `TaskFix` and one instance of `TaskFind`. If I query for all `Tasks` like this:

```
Task
  .fetchAll()
  .then(results => {
      res.json(results);
    });
```

the results look something like this

```
{
  {
    id       : 1,
    owner_id : 1,
    title    : "My TaskFind"
  },
  {
    id       : 2,
    owner_id : 1,
    title    : "My TaskFix"
  }
}
```

when really, I want them to look like this:

```
{
  {
    id       : 1,
    owner_id : 1,
    title    : "My TaskFind"
    additional_columns : ...
  },
  {
    id       : 2,
    owner_id : 1,
    title    : "My TaskFix"
    additional_columns : ...
  }
}
```

If I query them individually, I get the extra columns. For example:

```
TaskFix                       // (rather than just 'Task')
  .fetchAll()
  .then(results => {
      res.json(results);
    });
```

works and retrieves all additional columns.

Any idea if this is possible in Bookshelf.js? If not, is there a good workaround?

Comment: If i follow you, you just need define one to many relations: http://bookshelfjs.org/#one-to-many and when you build your query use fetch() with withRelated option: http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetch